# Is there any way to find out what all shell scripts failed in unix?

Tags: shell, unix

So currently I was looking for a solution which will give me the output of all failed UNIX shell scripts. so as per my understanding we can check if the last command was successful or not but do we have anything which can give me a list of shell scripts which got aborted on the server level.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: For every shell script which happens to be executed on a host by any user, you want to log which ones have a non-zero exit code?????? You would have to replace the bash, zsh, ksh etc. in /usr/bin by your own version (basically a wrapper around the original one), which would log the exit codes, and even this would not guarantee that a user installs his own shell locally. Having said this, I wonder what this is good for....

Comment: Do you mean output, or exit code?  How do you decide if a shell script failed?  Many badly-written shell scripts exit with 0 (success - the default)  even though they failed.  You also say "got aborted" - do you mean the SIGABRT signal?  Few shell scripts will fail in that way.